# multiple mysql joins use to much memory

Tags: mysql, join, memory

I have about twenty rather small tables (the largest has about 2k rows, normaly about 100 rows, with from 4 up to 20 columns each) I try to join by

```
select  ... from table1
left join table2 on table1.name = table2.t2name
left join table3 on table1.name = table3.othername
left join table4 on table2.t2name = table4.something
and so on
```

in theory it should return about 2k rows with maybe 80 columns, so I guess that the amount of data itself is not the problem.
But it runs out of memory. From reading several posts here I figured out that mysql internaly makes a big "all x all"-table first and reduces it later. How can I force it to excute the join after each join first, that it takes a lot less memory?

Comment: How large are these tables?

Comment: I don't actually know (shame on me).  This is why I ask for your table sizes.  If they are all reasonably small, then maybe the out of memory error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I added the information you wanted; if I execute parts of the query, it works fine, only if I use all at once it complains that it did runs out on memory

Comment: It is doing an "all x" thing here, but do you see why?  You are joining `table1` to `table2` then to `table3`.  Then, you join `table2` to `table4`.  Do the math, maybe you are running out of memory.  I'm still suspicious of this however.

Comment: Also, you may want to post the entire query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: basicly I select all entries from the largest table, and add information from the smaler ones to it, according by values in the large table, as said parts the query are working fine, only putting everything together smashes it, so I dont have any other explanaition than "all x all"

Comment: Two points to explore: If you have no indices OR you are not using them (i.e. your WHERE is on non-indexed columns), you would be checking ALL vs ALL vs ALL vs ALL (full-table-scan). Second, you may wish to try wrapping each select by an external `select *` (separately) and have limiting conditions (WHEREs) within each internal select. This way, you will be assisting the DB to compare only the relevant records.

Comment: @FDavidov: the first advice: I dont use indices, thanks, I'll try that next; for the second part of your answer: I dont understand, sorry, I have not much experience in sql, can you give an example?

Comment: @user2567875, I'll post a schematic example of the general idea in a couple of minutes. Stay tuned...

Comment: MySQL loves joins, so the problem is more likely to be indexing than number of joins per se

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things clear, in your case the expected amount of data is not the problem.

What appears to be the problem is the fact that you are asking the system to compare A X B X C X D... rows (calculate what it means and you will get the picture).

The general idea described in one of my previous comments is to make you query look as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (select  ... from table1
                where .....
              ) A
LEFT JOIN SELECT * FROM (select ... from table2
                          where .....
                        ) B
ON A.name = B.t2name    
LEFT JOIN SELECT * FROM (select ... from table3
                          where .....
                        ) C
ON A.name = C.othername
LEFT JOIN SELECT * FROM (select ... from table4
                          where .....
                        ) D
ON B.name = D.something
```

In this way, and assuming that this is applicable in the sense that you do have conditions to put in the `where .....` clause of the inner selects, you will be reducing the number of records from each table that would need to be compared during the join.

Comment: thanks for the explaination, now I understand what you meant (I hope) - I'll try it and will report if this did work tonight